# jquery ui draggable constraints

Tags: jquery-ui

I've got jQuery UI draggable div (near 10000 px width) and I want to make such constraints so the left side of draggable div won't go ahead of left side of screen and right side of div won't go off right side. I tried to show it on the picture.
[image: div on screen]

It seems that rectangular constraints won't fit this case and I'm lost in that

To be more clear, here is example: http://full-demo.megaplan.ru/vacation/diagram/
There you can't go futher jan 2013 and before july 2007

Answer (score 1):

You could add a container between `my_DIV` and the draggable and set that container's width to `$('html').width()` to make it as wide as the screen; then position the container so that it's position matches the screen. The result would be a `<div>` that matches the inner rectangle on your diagram. Once that's in place you could use the normal `containment` option to keep the draggable on-screen.

For example:

```
<div class="draggable">
    <div id="container">
        <p class="ui-widget-header">Draggable</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Then size and position `#container` and use this:

```
$("#draggable").draggable({ containment: "#container" });
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/SG9KS/

Comment: thanks for reply, but imagine that your draggable div is 10000 pixel size and it's right side should not go any further than the right side of container div, so the left side should'n go any left further than the left side of div. P.S. Sorry for my english.

Comment: @Sandvich: So is my_DIV in your picture your draggable then?

Comment: yes, it should be draggable, I can show you an example of what I want: http://full-demo.megaplan.ru/vacation/diagram/ notice that you can't go further jan 2013 and before aug 2007

Comment: Isn't that just where the inner 50000px wide `<div>` ends though? Maybe add those details to your question in case someone else comes along with better ideas than I'm having.